# How to hide flag link if current user and author are same?

Tags: flags

I need to hide flag link if the logged in user and the author are same.  Please find below codes.

```
function MODULE-NAME_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args)
{
    global $user;
    if ($view->name == 'VIEW-NAME' && $display_id == 'DISPLAY-ID') {
        $node = node_load(arg(1));
        if($node->uid == $user->uid){
            //echo 'hide flag';
        }else{
            //echo 'show flag'; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Flag module? can you please add details.

Comment: Yes I am using flag module and displaying flag links using view. I need to show link only to other users other than author.

Comment: @akm your last comment should be an edit. Also, if you already tried something, examined some configuration forms etc - please share.

Comment: @akm I guess what you are trying to achieve can be done through the permission of the flags. However, As stated by the Molot please share your finding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a flag on nodes, you just need to set "Users may only flag content of others" in the **Flag access by content authorship** paragraph of the **FLAG ACCESS** options.